# How to edit UTF-8 files in vim on windows

Tags: windows, vim

I'm trying to edit UTF-8 text files using vim (7.3) on windows (prompt/powershell).

My _vimrc file is pretty simple:

```
set encoding=latin-1
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

The problem is, when editing a file that already exists, it (aparently) works. But If I use vim to create a new file, it doesn't write the same contents.

Let's say, I open a file using `vim myfile.txt`, that have this content:

```
discussão
```

If I `:wq` it everything is ok.

Now, if instead I'm creating a new file, after saving and reopening I get:

```
discussÃ£o
```

If I edit it to look like the first and save it, I can edit the file any number of times without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

and read `:help 'encoding'`.

In short, this option defines how Vim is going to treat text *internally*. It is usually set automatically by Vim to match your system's locale. If it can't get that information (or if your locale is `latin1`), Vim sets it to `latin1` which, obviously, sucks hard.

Your best bet is to explicitly set it to `utf-8`.

On the other hand, `set fileencoding=utf-8` is not needed and probably counterproductive because it is set by Vim for each buffer.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't worked, but now for some reason I found my prompt was set to use code page 1252 instead of the default (code page 850), I changed that and it worked the way you suggested, thanks.