# Hyphen converted to 'unknown character' when pasted to programs such as Putty, Notepad is OK

Tags: windows-7, vim, putty, utf-8, confluence

When a UTF-8-encoded hyphen (U+2010) is copied from a browser (I tried Firefox and IE) and  then pasted to programs such as Putty and Vim (the Windows variants), all hyphens are showed as 'unknown glyphs'. Pasting to Notepad works flawlessly. Copying/pasting in Debian/wheezy of the very same HTML text (copying from iceweasel, pasting to vim) also works as expected.

But the utf-8 character is not crippled. Saving to disk resp. copying and pasting of the crippled text works as designed.

The real problem that I have to solve is with Confluence and its export function to a docx file. HTML is displayed OK, docx shows the unsigned glyphs, copying from docx to Notepad shows the hyphens in the pasted text.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: [How to edit UTF-8 files in vim on windows](http://superuser.com/questions/599868/how-to-edit-utf-8-files-in-vim-on-windows), [How can I use UTF-8 on Linux from Windows 7 via PuTTY?](http://superuser.com/questions/264363/how-can-i-use-utf-8-on-linux-from-windows-7-via-putty?rq=1)

Comment: Techi007, thank you. I forgot to mention that the German unlauts are displayed as expected. For vim, encoding and fileencodings are set to utf-8. With encoding=latin1 the hyphens would have been displayed as  â€. Our Linux-machines are set to LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated further and found an explanation: Hyphen U+2010 is NOT contained in the most fonts, especially not in the fixed fonts which are usually needed in programs like Vim and PuTTY.

Thus, the solution of my Confluence problem is: when converting content of the Confluence wiki to a MS Word file format, choose 'Arial Unicode MS Standard' as the default font.